# Nested for loop breaks to Linq

Tags: linq, for-loop, nested

I'm pretty new to Linq and I am having troubles with creating the Linq equivalent of the below nested for loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < toCompare1.Length; i++)
{
      bool isUnique = true;

      for(int j = 0; j < toCompare2.Length; j++)
      {
             if(toCompare1[i].Contains(toCompare2[j]))
             {
                 isUnique = false;
                 break;
             }
      }

      if(isUnique == true)
      {
          uniqueValues.Add(toCompare1[i]);
      }
}
```

Currently, my draft code is something like this:

```
var unique =
    from c1 in toCompare1
    from c2 in toCompare2
    where !c1.Contains(c2)
    select c1;
```

But it duplicates the entries I want to have.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the types for compare1 and compare2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fluent syntax:

`toCompare1.Where(item => !toCompare2.Any(item2 => item.Contains(item2)))`

In query sytax:

```
from item1 in toCompare1
where !toCompare2.Any(item2 => item1.Contains(item2))
select item1;
```